# Alternative for df.withColumn in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am converting some long datatype to datetime using withColumn and below code, but what I notice that when using withColumn inside for loops is leading to poor query planning performance.

is there any other way I can achieve the below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
for col in list_of_columns:
    df = df.withColumn(col, F.from_utc_timestamp(F.from_unixtime(df[col] / 1000), "UTC"))
list_of_columns = [list of 20 columns]
```

Comment: what do you call `poor query planning performance` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can put that in a single `select` statement.

```py
no_change_columns = [col for col in df.columns if col not in list_of_columns]

df = df.select(
    *no_change_columns,
    *(
        F.from_utc_timestamp(F.from_unixtime(F.col(col) / 1000), "UTC").alias(col)
        for col in list_of_columns
    )
)
```